# changing a Javascript image on event listener click

Tags: javascript

i have a Div holding an image with the id sunset that i want to add an onclick to to change its width from the CSS 25% to 100%

cannot see why my code is not working

```
var content = document.getElementById("sunset");
var first_click = true;

content.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (first_click) {
        content.style.width = "100%";
    }

    else {
        content.style.width = "25%";
    }

});
```

CSS

```
#sunset{
    width:25%
}
```

Comment: add to img, width 100% to fill the expanded container.

Comment: You should change your attitude on Stack. Firstly, you take ages to react to questions and answers from people trying to help you or stop replying entirely. Secondly, you never seem to accept any answer / closing your questions (0 / 5). Keep in mind that people are helping you for free and investing their free time. Dont just dump your issues and ghost.

Answer (score 0):

The first if statement doesn't check if the first_click var is true (assuming that is what you intend to do). Since it is empty it would return false and the else statement would run, keeping your image at 25%.

try this:

```
var content = document.getElementById("sunset");
var first_click = true;

content.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (first_click == true) {
        content.style.width = "100%";
    }

    else {
        content.style.width = "25%";
    }

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the `if (first_click)` is equivalent to `if (first_click == true)` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding height to your container ? This should work

```js
var content = document.getElementById("sunset");
var first_click = true;

content.addEventListener("click", function () {

    if (first_click) {
        content.style.width = "100%";
     
        first_click = false;
    }

    else {
        content.style.width = "25%";
    }

});
```

```css
#sunset{
  width:25%;
  background: #000;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sunset"></div>
```

Comment: Height will automatically adjust with width, but I see other parts of your code that are an improvement that you should expand upon.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not toggling the `first_click` variable to `true` or `false` when the image is clicked. The code below fixes this by setting `first_click = !first_click`:

```js
var content = document.getElementById("sunset");
var first_click = true;
content.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (first_click) {
    content.style.width = "100%";
  } else {
    content.style.width = "25%";
  }
  first_click = !first_click;
});
```

```css
#sunset {
  width: 25%
}
```

```html
<img id="sunset" src="https://dummyimage.com/150/f8f">
```